# How to pass a value from controllers to service methods with decorator in nestjs?

Tags: node.js, http-headers, nestjs, decorator, typescript-decorator

I have a controller as follows:

```js
@Controller()
class UserController {
  @Post("/order")
  @ApiBearerAuth()
  async createOrder(@Body() order: Order, @GetHeaderItem("HEADER-ITEM") item: string) {
    return await this.adminService.setOrder(item, order);
  }
}
```

and in the service's methods, I do some logic with `item` as the first parameter:

```js
@Injectable()
class AdminService {
  async setOrder(item, order) {
    // code that uses item (1)
  }
  async setPurchase(item, purchase) {
   
  }
  async setDate(item, date) {
   
  }

}
```

Now I want to find a solution in order to get the `item` header value by using decorators
on each service's method, something like:

```js
@Injectable()
class AdminService {
  // record contains `item` also
  async setOrder(order, @WithItemFromHeader() record: RecordObject) {
  
  }
  async setPurchase(item, purchase, @WithItemFromHeader() record: RecordObject) {
   
  }
  async setDate(item, date, @WithItemFromHeader() record: RecordObject) {
   
  }

}
```

I appreciate any help from you in advance. I am not easy with `decorators` yet.
I think there should be reasonable solutions that don't need passing headers directly to the service methods.

Comment: Can you add a sample payload? And you mean request headers?

Comment: @CharchitKapoor the payload of data is not an issue for me, and yeah the headers of request

Comment: I suppose that we may need two decorators (`method` and `param`) to handle this

Comment: The fact that you pass data in the headers of your HTTP request is not something your service should be aware / concerned about. Just extract the data from the header as @CharchitKapoor suggests and pass it as a parameter to your service.

Comment: I think you didn't get my point of view on this challenge! I don't want to break the soc of the responsibility of the controller layer and service layer. I just want to do some logic before each service method something like pre handlers by using decorators syntax

Comment: To access request headers, I think you will have to go via controller itself

Comment: @CharchitKapoor I said that accessing just headers is not my desired goal.

Comment: Then you can use @Req to access the whole request object itself. I have updated the answer as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Header` decorator at the controller level, to access a particular header and pass it down. Something like this:

import { Controller, Get, Req } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request } from 'express';

```
@Controller('cats')
export class CatsController {
  @Get()
  findAll(@Header("myHeader") header: Any): string {
    console.log(header);
    return 'This action returns all cats';
  }
}
```

It is not tested, customized an example from the documentation, have a look [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#request-object)

To access the whole request object, you can try this:

```
@Controller()
class UserController {
  @Post("/order")
  @ApiBearerAuth()
  async createOrder(@Body() order: Order, @GetHeaderItem("HEADER-ITEM") item: string, @Req() request: Request) {
    return await this.adminService.setOrder(item, order);
  }
}
```

Now you can pass any data from the request object, to the service layer via the controller.